# how mapping of sfdisk partition size is working

Tags: linux, partition, python, opensuse, sfdisk

We are using a Python script for running sfdisk creating partitions on our Linux. 
The code is as below:

```
        stdin,stdout=\
        (lambda x:(x.stdin,x.stdout))\
        (subprocess.Popen(
            ["/sbin/sfdisk","-uM","--no-reread",device],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT))

#<start>;<size>;<id>;<bootable>;
    t="""0;95;83;
;160;b;*
;;E;
;0;;
;20;b;
;95;b;
;;b;
"""
    print "Writing\n%s"%(t,)
    stdin.write(t)
    stdin.close()

"""Explanation:
/ 100MB (hda1)
/mnt/system 175MB (hda2)
/mnt/configuration 25MB (hda5)
/mnt/logs 100MB (hda6)
/mnt/user 88MB (hda7)
"""
```

After running this command I am seeing that the explanation is correct and for example systm has 175 MB.  What I don't understand is how the size 95 is mapped to 100 Megabyte, 160 to 175, 20 to 25 and so on.

The other question is if I want to increase the size of system to 210 megabyte then what is correct number to write in the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, you have a slightly out-of-date `sfdisk` command, as since 2015 version 2.26 it no longer accepts `-uM`, which is used to set the default "unit".

The difference you are seeing is due to whether numbers are given in MB i.e. Megabytes (1000*1000) or MiB i.e. Mebibytes (1024*1024). 100MB is approximately 95MiB.

If you want to future proof your code against a newer `sfdisk` you should remove the `-uM` and assume sizes are in sectors of 512 bytes. 
The newer [version](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/sfdisk.8.html) allows you to give numbers with a suffix like `MiB`.

210MB can be calculated as:

```
echo '210*1000*1000/1024/1024' | bc
```

about 200MiB.